# How to remove the url format from the WEBSITE field in the user registry?

Tags: user-meta

I would like to use this field with only simple text input without turning it into a url (http://empresa.com.br), I will change the label to Company and take advantage of the field to insert simple text. can anybody help me? How can I put this function in my child theme’s functions.php?

Comment: What is the user registry? Are you trying to repurpose the url field in the edit user profile admin page to store a different value? You could just add extra fields to that page and store them in user meta, is there a reason you want to repurpose that specific field?

Comment: I'm assuming you mean the form when a user registers for your site. Googling "wordpress remove field on form" yields some good results which you might be able to adapt.

Comment: Hello guys, sorry I think it was confusing, see or print what I'm talking about [image](https://i.imgur.com/P8fYqxc.png)I'm talking about this field Site it is a standard field in the user registration in wordpress, so you don't need to create another field that works for internal search, I would like to use the same for text entry only, but it would be necessary to remove this "mask" with format "url" and leave only the name you enter "Company Name"